# Dynamic range compression - Need pseudo algorithm for normalizing a signal

Tags: normalization, dynamic-range-compression

I have a signal that is NOT an audio signal (but looks like an audio signal - probably you can even "play" it). I would like to amplify the signal in regions where its amplitude is low. In very rare occasions the signal amplitude may be too high so I want to decrease it a bit. At the beginning and at the end of the 'track' I have some noise.

I think what what I want is called "Dynamic range compression". Is this correct? How I do this programmatically? I need some pseudo-code.

[image]

Comment: Did you check http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10536/help-implementing-audio-dynamic-range-compression

Comment: *"Dynamc range compression"* is a good label.  so also is *"Level compression"* and *"Automatic Gain Control" (AGC)* are terms you might wanna look up.  **don't** confuse *"Level compression"* with *"Data compression"*.  two different things.  sometimes in the audio world it is ambiguous when someone refers to *"compression of audio"*.  to deal with the noise, you might need a "gate", which is also implemented with some audio level compressors.

Comment: @LaurentDuval-Yes. The question is a bit different. The answers: One of the answers is too generic the other one just provide some equations (and some possible drawback for using those equations as they are optimized for voice).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson-THANKS. Good to know. I hope I can find more info now by searching for "Automatic Gain Control"

Comment: Have you seen this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm ?

Comment: @MBaz, i don't think that mu-law or A-law (or arcsinh-law) is what this AGC is about.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson You're right, but to me, the OP's problem sounds more like companding than AGC.

Comment: @MBaz, *"...normalizing" a signal..."* sounds exactly like AGC.  Level compression with an $\infty$ to 1 compression ratio.  sounds like envelope-following and then dividing by the smoothed envelope.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson-I added an image of my signal. Can I still use an envelope? If so, can you explain in a few words the basics.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson AGC uses a feedback loop and has a time constant, and is better suited to track slow changes in input signal power. I don't believe this is what the OP wants, but I may have misunderstood their question. Companding, on the other hand, is an instantaneous mapping from one amplitude to another. I'll rest my case now.

Comment: no @MBaz, that is only one method of doing AGC. AGC can also be done just like any level compressor with the compression ratio cranked up to $\infty$ to 1.  and you can use a sliding max window (along with another LPF) to do envelope detection.  (the "inverted" envelope would be applied to the delayed signal that is delayed by 1/2 of the max window width.)  the OP wants to **normailze** the amplitude of his audio-like signal.  OP said nothing about undoing the compression with expansion.  if only the compression is done, the $\mu$-law compression changes the waveform shape.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: so @SolarWind, it is a uni-polar signal?  only non-negative values?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson-yes.

Answer (score 3):

from your posted waveform, i am assuming that this is a unipolar signal.  that is

$$ x[n] \ge 0 $$

in audio, it would be the same, except that we would be working on $|x[n]|$ instead.

so first you want a sliding maximum of your signal, where the window length is $L$.

$$ x_1[n] = \max_{0 \le i < L} \Big| x[n-i] \Big|  $$

since your input signal $x[n]$ appears to be unipolar, you can leave off the absolute value operation.

then you want to apply a low-pass filter (LPF) to that sliding max.  you want the gain of the LPF at DC (0 Hz) to be 1 (or 0 dB gain).  a simple first-order LPF is

$$ \begin{align}
 x_2[n] &= (1-p) \cdot x_1[n] + p \cdot x_2[n-1] \\ 
\\
        &= x_1[n] + p \cdot (x_2[n-1] - x_1[n]) \\ 
\\
        &= x_2[n-1] + (1-p) \cdot (x_1[n] - x_2[n-1]) \\ 
\end{align} $$

$p$ is the pole value of the LPF and

$$ 0 < 1-p \ll 1 $$

so

$x_2[n]$ will be an envelope for your input signal $x[n]$ and will be delayed by about half of the max window length plus about 4 times the "time constant" of the LPF:

$$d = \frac{L}{2} - \frac{4}{\log(p)} \quad \quad \text{samples}$$.

so, to normalize, you want to invert (compute the reciprocal of) the envelope $x_2[n]$ and multiply your input signal by that inverted envelope.  the inverted envelope is

$$ x_3[n] = \frac{A}{x_2[n] + \epsilon} $$

$A$ is the normalized amplitude you want (it can be $A=1$ or $A=$ any other positive number that you like).  $\epsilon$ is a tiny number, much smaller than most of your non-zero $x[n]$ that you need to add to the denominator to keep from dividing by zero (which is a **bad thing**).

but you should line up the signal and the delayed inverted envelope, so your normalized output is also delayed by $d$ samples (defined above):

$$ y[n] = x_3[n] \cdot x[n-d] $$

the most computationally expensive operation is the sliding max.  we were just talking about this sliding max in the *music-dsp* mailing list.  i will dig up C code for it and post that in a following answer.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will try to implement this in Pascal. One question: As you can see, my signal has some areas where it is flat (no peaks). Will this affect the algorithm in any way?

Comment: about the flat parts, it will **still** look for the sliding max.  but when it computes the inverse gain, it will be limited by the setting of that $\epsilon$ parameter.  this prevents division by zero and prevents those flat areas from being amplified by a gain of $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

here's an efficient sliding maximum algorithm that has cost that is $O(\log_2(L))$.  below `window_width` is $L$.

comes from

> Brookes: "Algorithms for Max and Min Filters with Improved Worst-Case Performance" IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON CIRCUITS AND SYSTEMS—II: ANALOG AND DIGITAL SIGNAL PROCESSING, VOL. 47, NO. 9, SEPTEMBER 2000

```
#define A_REALLY_LARGE_NUMBER 3.40e38

typedef struct
   {
   unsigned long window_width;          // array_size/2 < window_width <= array_size
   unsigned long array_size;            // must be power of 2 for this simple implementation
   unsigned long input_index;           // the actual sample placement is at (array_size + input_index);
   float* big_array_base;               // the big array is malloc() separately and is actually twice array_size;
   } search_tree_array_data;


void initSearchArray(unsigned long window_width, search_tree_array_data* array_data)
   {
   array_data->window_width = window_width;

   array_data->array_size = 1;
   window_width--;
   while (window_width > 0)
      {
      array_data->array_size <<= 1;
      window_width >>= 1;
      }
   // array_size is a power of 2 such that
   // window_width <= array_size < 2*window_width
   // array_size = 2^ceil(log2(window_width)) = 2^(1+floor(log2(window_width-1)))

   array_data->input_index = 0;

   array_data->big_array_base = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*2*array_data->array_size);        // dunno what to do if malloc() fails.

   for (unsigned long n=0; n<2*array_data->array_size; n++)
      {
      array_data->big_array_base[n] = -A_REALLY_LARGE_NUMBER;        // init array.
      }                                                              // array_base[0] is never used.
    }



/*
 *   findMaxSample(value, &array_data) will place "value" into the circular
 *   buffer in the latter half of the array pointed to by array_data->big_array_base .
 *   it will then compare the value in "value" to its "sibling" value, takes the
 *   greater of the two and then pops up one generation to the parent node where 
 *   this parent also has a sibling and repeats the process.  since the other parent  
 *   nodes already have the max value of the two child nodes, when getting to the
 *   top-level parent node, this node will have the maximum value of all the samples
 *   in the big_array.  the number of iterations of this loop is ceil(log2(window_width)).
 */

float findMaxSample(float value, search_tree_array_data* array_data)
   {
   register float* big_array = array_data->big_array_base;

   register unsigned long index = array_data->array_size + array_data->input_index;        // our main buffer is in the latter half of the big array.

   while (index > 1UL)
      {
      big_array[index] = value;

      register float sibling_value = big_array[index ^ 1UL];        // toggle LSB, the upper bits of the sibling address are the same.

      if (value < sibling_value)
         {
         value = sibling_value;                        // use maximum of the two values
         }

      index >>= 1;                                     // parent address is index/2 (drop remainder or "sibling bit")
      }

   array_data->input_index++;
   if (array_data->input_index >= array_data->window_width)
      {
      array_data->input_index = 0;
      }

   return value;
   }
```

Comment: Interesting code. Unfortunately I cannot see what exactly is this pair of functions doing; (the findmax I mean) i.e., how do we use them in our main code ? And how does it compress a given buffer of samples ? (and in O($\log_2(L)$)) time?)

Comment: it's for envelope following, @Fat32.  it's there to find the maximum value of the most current $L$ samples.  so the output of this filter will  often be a piecewise-constant function and will always "cover" the previous $L$.  the compression is done in the other answer.  i thought it best to put the $$ x_1[n] = \max_{0 \le i < L} \big| x[n] \big|$$ in another answer.

Comment: ok... I see...thanks!  btw you mean $$ x_1[n] = \max_{0 \le i < L} \Big| x[n-i] \Big|  $$ (excerpted from your other answer). To Sum Up: The **code** finds the **max** of the most recent $L$ samples of the audio buffer, and then **compression** is perfomed according to the other answer. What is the recommended min/max value of L? (assuming 44,100 Hz audio). I still have doubt of how can we find the **max** in logarithmic time? Also the sliding window is jumping by $L$ samples (into a complete new set of samples) or just moving one sample. I think I should post this to the other aswer

Comment: yes.  thanks for the correction.  i dunno, for an audio compressor/limiter, maybe $L=$ `window_width` can be about 4000 for 100 ms.  that is a perceptual issue.  it also depends on how fast you want your compressor/limiter to *"pump"*.  the algorithm for a compressor/limiter/gate is not **exactly** what is described above.  the attack time and decay time on the envelope would be different for an audio compressor/limiter/gate.  (and i didn't put in the gate alg. anyway.)

Comment: oh so your answer is specifically for the provided example signal of the OP... Indeed I think it's not a compressor at all as the OP wants something more of a dynamic range normalizer...

Comment: well, it's an AGC implemented without feedback and, in my opinion, equivalent to an audio level compressor with a sliding max on the input, identical attack and decay times (regarding the LPF), compression ratio set to $\infty$ to 1, and the "knee" set to $20 \log_{10}(A)$ in dB relative to whatever dB the level $1$ is.  and delay compensating for the delay in the sliding max and the simple LPF.