# signal saturation

Tags: signal-analysis, scaling, simulink

My signal is an actuator displacement signal. It is a sinusoidal signal with the max amplitude of 10cm. I want to clip amplitude at 7 cm in Simulink. But with saturation block, I will get flat clipping, in fact, is there any way to avoid having a flat clipping of signal?

Comment: to be honest, my signal is an actuator displacement and is a sinusoidal signal with the max amplitude of 10 cm I want to clip amplitude at 7 cm in simulink. but with saturation block, I will get flat clipping, in fact, is there any way to avoid having a flat clipping of signal?

Comment: Normalize your signal they multiply it in 7.

Comment: take a look at memoryless nonlinearity: https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/memorylessnonlinearity.html

Comment: the Saleh model is what I use.  I do not use matlab, the doc says complex baseband

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do [dynamic range compression.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression)

Have a look at [this answer to another question.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/10538/80) If your question is different, I'll re-open it.